# Order by clause not working for string in Play Ebean

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I want to order the list bases on string but ebean is giving an error. here is my query.

```
 ExpressionList<Application> query = find.query()
                .where();
 query.setFirstRow(start * 10)
                .setMaxRows(max);
 query.orderBy("applicationVerification.verificationStatus like 'PENDING%' desc");

java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting [like] to be asc or desc?
        at io.ebean.OrderBy.isAscending(OrderBy.java:460)
        at io.ebean.OrderBy.parseProperty(OrderBy.java:445)
        at io.ebean.OrderBy.parse(OrderBy.java:414)
        at io.ebean.OrderBy.<init>(OrderBy.java:58)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like operator is used for WHERE clause and it doesn’t work for OrderBy, so you can change your code to:

```
 query.orderBy("applicationVerification.verificationStatus desc");
```

or

```
query.orderBy().desc("applicationVerification.verificationStatus");
```

More info on eban site https://ebean.io/docs/query/orderBy